# How can I re-write this code without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I rewrite this code without using jQuery? I need to do it in a mobile app where I can't use jQuery.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url:"../REST/session.aspx?_method=put",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObject, null,4),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: onSuccessLogin,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions){
                    alert(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
                }    

        });
```

Comment: jQuery is javascript... You want to stop using jQuery framework and write it in pure javascript? If yes, then tell why ;)

Comment: Because I'm developing one mobile web app. Some low configuration mobile's doesn't support jQuery so then i try to write in java script.

Comment: simplest way is to look at the source code for jQuery.ajax function

Comment: then you should google for XMLHttpRequest, there's lot of good stuff out there.

Comment: @Liviu T: *"simplest way is to look at the source code for jQuery.ajax function"* You've obviously never looked at the jQuery source code. ;-) Convolutely doesn't *half* say it.

Comment: I want to call the web service by using java script. no jQuery od ajax.

Comment: @Durai: I took the liberty of rewording your question a bit so people understand it better at first glance.

Comment: @Durai: You cannot do this without Ajax. I mean, you can, but that would redirect to the REST client page and people would probably see the JSON response directly in the browser. I don't think the service is designed to be accessed directly.

Comment: Data object contains:  dataObject = {Username:uname,Password:pword,Domain:domain,WindowsUser:windowsuser};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status != 200) {
    // What you want to do on failure
    alert(xmlhttp.status + " : " + xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    // What you want to do on success
    onSuccessLogin();
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "../REST/session.aspx?_method=put", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); // For no cache
xmlhttp.send("data=" + JSON.stringify(dataObject, null,4));
```

As for how to do more stuff with only javascript without jQuery library take a look at [W3Schools AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/default.asp) or [Mozilla - Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest)

And as duri said, you will have to find a way to convert dataObject to string, as not all browsers support JSON object.

Comment: JSON object is not supported in every browser.

Comment: and I also call onsuccesslogin method. where  can I call that function?

Comment: @duri I'm not sure if there is default JSON object or somethign similar in all browsers, so Durai will ahve to find a way to convert dataObject to string. But as I have no idea what does dataObject look like, I can't help there.

Comment: @Durai You can call onsuccesslogin from inside xmlhttp.onreadystatechange function, when xmlhttp.readyState == 4 (complete) and xmlhttp.status == 200 (OK).

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
//retrieves the xmlHttpRequest Object
function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
    //will store the refrence to the xmlHttpRequest Object
    var xmlHttp;
    //if running in internet explorer version below 7
    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
            try{
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                xmlHttp = false;
            }
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    if(!xmlHttp)
        alert("Error Creating the xmlHttpObject");      
    else
        return xmlHttp;
}

function callThisFunction()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0)
    {

            var queryString = JSON.stringify(dataObject, null,4);

            var url = "../REST/session.aspx?_method=put";

            xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryString.length);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = checkHandleServerResponse;         
            xmlHttp.send(queryString);  
    }
}


function checkHandleServerResponse()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
            var JSONFile = 'jsonFormatData = '+xmlHttp.responseText;
            eval(JSONFile);
            if(jsonFormatData.description == 'Success')
            {
                //showDialog('Success','Login Successful','success',3);
                location.href='default.aspx';   
                //setTimeout(function(){location.href='myGrupio.php';},3000);
            }
            else
                showDialog('Error','You Need a Valid Login.','error',3);
        }
        else if(xmlHttp.status == 400)
        {
            setTimeout( function()
                        {
                            alert('you have error');
                        },3000);
        }
        else 
            alert("Error Code is "+xmlHttp.status)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Ajax request itself, have a look at the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest) object ([special treatment for IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

To parse the JSON response (`dataType: 'json'`), use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox) (you might need the [`json2.js` library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)).

Answer (score 0):

jquery is already javascript. It's a library, entirely written in javascript. So you can use it within every javascript project. If you want to write a rest client yourself, you might look at [this article](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-javascript.html)

Comment: Despite his phrasing, it was perfectly clear what he was really asking.

Comment: I want to call the web service by using java script. no jQuery od ajax.

Comment: since you're doing asynchronous javascript to call the rest interface you'll have to use ajax. ajax is just shorthand for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. So it is as well as jquery 100%, pure javascript.
But it does make sense to not use a library like jquery when you run into compatibility issues with other libraries...

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) edition - very light - 17KB minified. 1.0 is alpha now, but I think it will be more stable and portable than self-baked code.